# Prevent touchend while scrolling in iPhone/iPad

Tags: jquery, html, ios, iphone, ipad

I have a HTML page with some expandable divs. Those divs can be expanded and closed onclick (On the div). But it creates problem in iPhone/iPad while scrolling the page. If I touch on the div and scroll the page, it also fires a touchend event and that expands the div. I want to prevemt that.
My JS code example:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click touchend', '.mydiv', function() {
        var clickedItem = $(this);
        var parent = clickedItem.parent('li');
        setTimeout(function() {
            parent.removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
        },1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I am not using jquery mobile. This is just a webpage. Can I use jquery touchmove or something?